# Error in installing a modified package from local modifed zip file

Tags: windows, r, zip, package

I found a small bug in a R package. I communicated with the package author to update the code. While waiting for the author action to fix the bug, I am trying to fix the bug on my local version of the package.

I changed the R code, and also updated the MD5 of the associated file. The package is re-zipped, and I use this command to install it:

```
install.packages("path/to/the/file/modified_package.zip", repos = NULL)
```

it seems the installation is going well:

```
Installing package(s) into ‘C:/Users/Me/Documents/R/win-library/2.15’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
package ‘x’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

However, when I try to load the package, there is an error:

```
> library(x)
Error in library(x) : ‘x’ is not a valid installed package
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just zip up the directories; you need to rebuild the package.

There are loads of guides around on how to build R packages.  The easiest way (imho) is to use the `devtools` package.

```
library(devtools)

build("path/to/the/package")
install.packages("path/to/built/package.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

Or

```
build("path/to/the/package", binary = TRUE)
install.packages("path/to/built/package.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
```

You'll also need Rtools if you are running Windows.  Install it with the `installr` package.

```
library(installr)
install.Rtools()
```

Comment: Thanks. Just I want to add that I was not able to get Rtools working with devtools because of some version mismatching to be fixed in devtools. However, it worked fine using RStudio: install.packages("path/to/the/package", type="source")

Comment: A good post about setting path when installing Rtools: http://www.biostat.wisc.edu/~kbroman/Rintro/Rwinpack.html

Comment: Maybe it depends on the environment, but similar process for a modified package has failed for me, when I used `install.packages()`. However, it has been successful after I used `install_local()`. I guess, you have meant that.